# Difference between including everything on index and showing all different pages?

Tags: php, include

As I am learning about including pages on the index instead of showing the pages itself, I have a hard time with it. So I was wondering something.

Is there any difference between using something like this to switch to show different pages on index.php:

```
switch($page) {
case 'page1':
    $pagefile='page1';
    break;
case 'page2':
    $pagefile='page2';
    break;
case 'page3':
    $pagefile='page3';
    break;
case 'page4':
    $pagefile='page4';
    break;
default:
    $pagefile='home';
}


require_once(''.$pagefile.'.php');
```

and just showing the php files itself? As in functionality or security etc?

Comment: There is no difference.. This one is more dynamic then static rendering of pages..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing like this allows you to include some other thing in the same page and not have to repeat it on every page.

Let's say you have an header, a menu, your page, and the footer.
Using this method you can do this :

```
<?php

$whiteList = array('index', 'page1', 'page2');

$page = in_array($_GET['page'], $whiteList) ? $_GET['page'] : 'index';

include('header.html');
include('menu.html');
include($page.'.php');
include('footer.html')

?>
```

EDIT : It's a very good thing to have an entry point to your application.

Let's say tomorrow you want to know how many total pages have been viewed, you can just add a counter in your index.php script (without repeating it in every other pages).

EDIT 2 : Note that the above code won't work everytime (there might be some error), but I won't spoil you the fun of finding out why. ;-)

Comment: Yeah okay I get that. I am learning stuff like this as well but I mean as if one is better than the other. EDIT: Your edit is a good example.

Comment: This is way better.
Big applications, or framework use something called "bootstrap" where they load the config, prepare the application, and load the routes to redirect the user to the appropriate resource.

Comment: Okay so you are saying it is more convenient and faster to work with though it's not that you can do more / better things with this right? Anyway I really appreciate the help

Comment: You can do things only once when needed. And it avoids replicating code, so it's optimized in term of disk usage (haha). No more seriously it's a very conveniant and safe way of working I think any web dev would recommend this approach above the other one.

Comment: Okay thanks. I was actually wondering if it's necessary for a small project but it's really just more conveniant and you dont have to replicate codes which also means it's optimized in term of disk usage (haha). Thank you. I got the answer I was looking for +1

Answer (score 1):

U can use it for security i mean for example UR index.php be like this

`include($_GET['page']."sec.php");`

so the client won't see any page name only `index.php?page=example`
and there are page name `examplesec.php` at UR folder so the client don't know the name of UR pages only see what `?page=the_page_name` and U can change sec by and thing UR name or zzz

- index.php will include another things at page like header , footer , side bar ... ect that will be at all pages

and U should use `include_once` so if there are any problem this will stop it

and for the pages is important use `require_once` so if the page not found the script will stop

Answer (score 0):

Try it with this, it is smart to check the name because that way you protect sensitive files

```
if(in_array($page, ['page1', 'page2', 'page3', 'page4'])) {
    $pagefile = $page;
} else {
    $pagefile = 'home';
}

include($pagefile.'.php');
```